# Protocol buffers compiler maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, protocol-buffers

I have  protocol buffers compiler plugin configured in my POM that is executed whenever the project is built. This complier plugin works fine in windows but now I moved my project to  an ubuntu PC & need to used a suitable alterntive for this.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-protoc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir dir="src/main/resources/protocolBuffers/compiled" />
                            <path id="proto.path">
                                <fileset dir="src/main/proto">
                                    <include name="**/*.proto" />
                                </fileset>
                            </path>
                            <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="proto.files" refid="proto.path" />
                            <exec executable="src/main/resources/protocolBuffers/compiler/protoc" failonerror="true">
                                <arg value="--java_out=src/main/resources/" />
                                <arg value="-I${project.basedir}/" />
                                <arg line="${proto.files}"/>
                            </exec>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I see the following output when trying to build the project in Ubuntu netbeans

```
--- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (compile-protoc) @ Px10App ---
Executing tasks
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.638s
Finished at: Tue Mar 25
Final Memory: 9M/105M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (compile-protoc) on project Px10App: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "src/main/resources/protocolBuffers/compiler/protoc": error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
```

How to make compiler plugin work in Ubuntu netbeans ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your protoc executable could not be executed on linux. You should download and compile protoc for linux and once you do it you will be able to use this maven plug-in as you are using it on windows.

You have detailed instruction for this [here](http://techtraits.com/build%20management/maven/2011/09/10/compiling-protocol-buffers-from-maven.html)

Comment: Thanks .. Also I think there's also an `apt-get` package for protobuf compiler. Do you have an idea about which package needs to be installed for that ?

Comment: I think this is it: `sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler` [http://devblog.corditestudios.com/blog/2012/08/09/setting-up-protobuf/]

Answer (score 11):

This one comes with protoc built-in (it's originally based on igor-petruk/protobuf-maven-plugin, but it comes with protoc binaries bundled for Linux, Mac/OSX, and Windows). At runtime it detects the platform and executes the corresponding binary

https://github.com/os72/protoc-jar-maven-plugin

Here's an example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
    <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <protocVersion>2.4.1</protocVersion>
                <inputDirectories>
                    <include>src/main/protobuf</include>
                </inputDirectories>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: added example and some wording

Comment: just for anyone want try newer version of protobuf, this plugin use [embedded protobuf](https://github.com/os72/protoc-jar/tree/master/bin), so there is no way to change that without modify source code.

Comment: hi @user1686407 that is not entirely accurate. yes a few protoc versions are embedded and the latest is the default. but other versions will be downloaded from maven central

Comment: no offence, if it can download from maven central, why it need bundle protoc binary? why it need update the plugin to support newer version?

Comment: yes nowadays it's not that critical to update the embedded version anymore. the history of the plugin goes back to times when no protoc binaries were available for download. and it's still "nice" to have something self-contained

Answer (score 7):

A good cross-platform solution is to use the protoc binary artifacts available in Maven Central.

The simple configuration changes needed to your pom.xml are described in the com.google.protobuf.tools: maven-protoc-plugin documentation ["Resolving Protoc Artifact From Maven Central Repo"](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/examples/protoc-artifact.html)

In case the link disappears, the salient part is:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:2.6.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: This is failing for me in Jenkins (works on local).

Comment: For anyone else who encounters this answer, this plugin is not currently being maintained. The current version is 0.6.1 FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

You still need protoc 
but I think it is nicer to use a a protobuf maven plugin to compile proto files

I use this in my projects

```html
<plugin>
 <groupId>com.github.igor-petruk.protobuf</groupId>
     <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
       <execution>
        <configuration>
         <cleanOutputFolder>false</cleanOutputFolder>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
         <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
       </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```